# How could SharedPreferences.Editor.commit() not be able to write successfully and what to do about it?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

`commit()` returns a value, so there must be a chance it couldn't write successfully. If it is absolutely critical that our value be written, what can we do if the return value is false? What conditions would cause it to not be written successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation

> Note that when two editors are modifying preferences at the same time, the last one to call commit wins. If you don't care about the return value and you're using this from your application's main thread, consider using apply() instead.

So if its returning false it means that you have another thread trying to commit a transaction, just make your shared preferences access thread safe and you will be sure that it will always return true (and remember that shared prefs do not support multi process)